How to ensure you know you are frying/no water in sauce
When frying foods, the food you add will have water in it, which is released into the oil during the cooking process.  This applies to vegetables, proteins or whatever it may be, and the more food you add, the more water is released.
Sometimes when attempting to fry, I cannot discern whether the food is frying or boiling as a result of water being released from the food.
Correct me if I’m wrong, but I think I read when frying the oil is meant to be so hot that as water is released, it quickly evaporated due to the instant heat or won’t be noticeable in cooking. I can see why the latter might apply to deep frying, since any amount of water released is far less than the oil.
So how to know or ensure you are frying and not boiling, is boiling at some point unavoidable and is the answer different depending on the frying method, e.g., stir, shallow and deep fry?


Sometimes when attempting to fry I cannot discern whether the food is frying or boiling as a result of water being released from food.

Well, both. Always. If the food contains water, and is heated above boiling temperature, the water in it is boiling off.
It sounds like you’re describing a situation where so much water is present outside the food, and so little heat is being released by the pan, that the surface of the food is unable to rise above boiling temperature. In addition to all the clearly visible boiling water around the food, the most noticeable symptom would be that the surface of the food does not brown (which requires temperatures above boiling temperature).
